# Using Bottle WSGI, there is an approx 1 minute delay in web transactions

Tags: python, delay, bottle, delayed-execution

I have a Python programm that shows statistics of equipments with the use of simple web pages and matplotlib charts in the form of images. Since a while and I can't relate to any event, there is a delay of approx 1 minute when I call the first main menu page and one of the pages that generate and disply the graph images.
I can't find anything on the internet related to this issue I have.

I put timestamps in the code to see where the time is spent and it seem to be outside of my processing statements or within the Bottle functions...
Sample of my program without the processing statement but showing how Bottle functions are used:

```
from bottle import route, run, debug, template, request, static_file
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
import time
import os
import sqlite3
import matplotlib
import glob
matplotlib.use('Agg') # this set the matplotlib backend to generate
                      # a .png file when creating charts
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import requests


def stamp(msg):
    global ts
    t1 = time.time()
    print("Step " + msg + ", duration=" + '%4.2f' % ((t1-ts)*1000) + "ms")
    ts = t1

# Initial html page. Very simple for now.
@route('/')
def mainpage():
    ''' Display main page menu '''
    global passes1

    stamp("Entering mainpage()")
    
    passes1 = 0 # Lorsqu'on revient à l'écran principal, on réinitialise les passes des autres écrans.


# Adresse IP du client
    client_ip = request.environ.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    log.info(datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + ' Adresse IP du client: {}\n'.format(client_ip))

    stamp("Exiting mainpage()")

    return template('midnite.tpl', Hostname=hostname) # Bottle template


# Rapport global du système électrique du chalet
@route('/mesures1', method='GET')
def mesures1():
    ''' Page des mesures '''

    stamp("Entering mesures1")
    
    ''' Removed processing statements...'''
    if passes1 > 1:
        stamp("Exiting mesures1 with charts")

        return template('mesures1.tpl', Hostname=hostname, \
            Vbatt=str(float(vbatt)/10), Vpann=str(float(vpann)/10), \
            Apann=str(float(apann)/10), KWHc=str(float(kwhc)/10), \
            Wpann=str(wpann), Wload=str(float(penvbatt*penaload)/100), \
            Aload=str(float(penaload)/10), Abatt = str(float(penabatt)/10), \
            Vbattp=str(float(penvbatt)/10), Echarg=etatscharge[echarg >> 8], \
            Vbatt1=str(float(vbatt1)/10), Vpann1=str(float(vpann1)/10), \
            Apann1=str(float(apann1)/10), KWHc1=str(float(kwhc1)/10), Wpann1=str(wpann1), \
            Echarg1=etatscharge[echarg1 >> 8], Kwhpancumul=str(float(kwhpancumul)/10), \
            Wpantotal=str(float(wpantotal)), Apantotal=str(float(apantotal)/10), \
            Couleur="color-black", \
            Inv=str(inv[1]) + " " + str(inv[2]), \
            Ags=str(ags[1]) + " " + str(ags[2]), \
            Bmk=str(bmk[1]) + " " + str(bmk[2]) + " " + str(bmk[3]) + " " + str(bmk[4]), \
            Invt=str(inv[0]), Agst=str(ags[0]), Bmkt=str(bmk[0]), \
            Date_time=str(date_time), Battpctfull=str(penbpctfull), periode=(per), \
            persui=(psuiv), perpre=(pprec), Interval=(interval), Image=(image), Tc=(tc), Td=(td))
    else:
        ''' Removed processing statements '''
        
        stamp("Exiting mesures1 without chart")
        
        return template('mesures1.tpl', Hostname=hostname, \
            Vbatt=str(float(s[1]/10)), Vpann=str(float(s[2]/10)), \
            Apann=str(float(s[3]/10)), KWHc=str(float(s[4]/10)), \
            Wpann=str(s[5]), Wload=str(float(s[7]*s[10]/100)), \
            Aload=str(float(s[10]/10)), Abatt = str(float(s[8]/10)), \
            Vbattp=str(float(s[7]/10)), Echarg=etatscharge[s[6]>>8], \
            Vbatt1=str(float(s[12]/10)), Vpann1=str(float(s[13]/10)), \
            Apann1=str(float(s[14]/10)), KWHc1=str(float(s[15]/10)), Wpann1=str(s[16]), \
            Echarg1=etatscharge[s[17]>>8], Kwhpancumul=str(float((s[4]+s[15])/10)), \
            Wpantotal=str(float(s[5]+s[16])), Apantotal=str(float((s[3]+s[14])/10)), \
            Couleur="color-black", \
            Inv=str(0) + " " + str(0), \
            Ags=str(0) + " " + str(0), \
            Bmk=str(0) + " " + str(0) + " " + str(0) + " " + str(0), \
            Invt=" ", Agst=" ", Bmkt=" ", \
            Date_time=s[0], Battpctfull=str(s[11]), periode=(0), \
            persui=(0), perpre=(0), Interval=(interval), Image=(image), Tc=str(0), Td=str(0))


# This is the special web page or route that feed the <img src=image.jpg> in
# the mesuresx.tpl template. Note the full path to the working directory or root
# in the return static_file statement.
@route('/static/<filepath:path>')
def server_static(filepath):

    stamp("Passing in server_static()")
    return static_file(filepath, root='./')




# MAIN PROGRAM

ts = time.time()
stamp("Start of program")

''' Variable declarations, etc.'''

stamp("run(host... statement")
#debug(True)
run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

Here is the output of running the program with the recored delays:

```
(base) pi@raspberrypi:/usr/local/bin/midnite $ python midnitenp.py
Step Start of program, duration=0.00ms
Step run(host... statement, duration=0.13ms
Bottle v0.12.23 server starting up (using WSGIRefServer())...
Listening on http://0.0.0.0:8080/
Hit Ctrl-C to quit.

Step Entering mainpage(), duration=50455.94ms
Step Exiting mainpage(), duration=0.86ms
192.168.2.38 - - [25/Nov/2022 16:23:04] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 420
192.168.2.38 - - [25/Nov/2022 16:23:04] "GET /IMG_0797b.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 749
Step Entering mesures1, duration=59996.11ms
Step Exiting mesures1 without chart, duration=6.23ms
192.168.2.38 - - [25/Nov/2022 16:24:04] "GET /mesures1 HTTP/1.1" 200 4372
Step Entering mesures1, duration=40161.20ms *This 40 seconds is key/think time.*
Step Exiting mesures1 with charts, duration=14153.92ms
192.168.2.38 - - [25/Nov/2022 16:24:59] "GET /mesures1?periode=2022-11-20+09%3A05%3A34&interval=1m12 HTTP/1.1" 200 4513
Step Passing in server_static(), duration=404.65ms
192.168.2.38 - - [25/Nov/2022 16:24:59] "GET /static/m1669393495.png HTTP/1.1" 200 116203
Step Entering mainpage(), duration=45432.64ms
Step Exiting mainpage(), duration=0.98ms
192.168.2.38 - - [25/Nov/2022 16:25:45] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 420
192.168.2.38 - - [25/Nov/2022 16:25:45] "GET /IMG_0797b.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 749
```

Thanks so much for your help!

Regards,

Daniel.

EDIT:

I ran the same program on a Debian VM instance on my Macbook. When I use Firefox browser locally pointing to localhost:8080, there are no delay and the program run like a charm. When I use Safari on the MacOS side, I get the delay. I tried Chrome on the MacOS side and no delay... To make sure, I tried Firefox on Debian and Chrome on MacOS on the Raspberry instance and it works like a charm...

Here is the example using Chrome on MacOS pointing to the Raspberry as used above:

```
Step Start of program, duration=0.00ms
Step run(host... statement, duration=0.13ms
Bottle v0.12.23 server starting up (using WSGIRefServer())...
Listening on http://0.0.0.0:8080/
Hit Ctrl-C to quit.

Step Entering mainpage(), duration=1901.72ms
Step Exiting mainpage(), duration=0.45ms
192.168.2.38 - - [25/Nov/2022 18:45:54] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 420
192.168.2.38 - - [25/Nov/2022 18:45:54] "GET /IMG_0797b.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 749
Step Entering mesures1, duration=1836.83ms
Step Exiting mesures1 without chart, duration=6.75ms
192.168.2.38 - - [25/Nov/2022 18:45:56] "GET /mesures1 HTTP/1.1" 200 4372
Step Entering mainpage(), duration=6748.66ms
Step Exiting mainpage(), duration=0.98ms
192.168.2.38 - - [25/Nov/2022 18:46:03] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 420
192.168.2.38 - - [25/Nov/2022 18:46:03] "GET /IMG_0797b.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 749
Step Entering mesures1, duration=6192.02ms
Step Exiting mesures1 without chart, duration=4.01ms
192.168.2.38 - - [25/Nov/2022 18:46:09] "GET /mesures1 HTTP/1.1" 200 4372
Step Entering mesures1, duration=2804.48ms
Step Exiting mesures1 with charts, duration=14160.78ms
192.168.2.38 - - [25/Nov/2022 18:46:26] "GET /mesures1?periode=2022-11-20+09%3A05%3A34&interval=1m12 HTTP/1.1" 200 4513
Step Passing in server_static(), duration=357.36ms
192.168.2.38 - - [25/Nov/2022 18:46:26] "GET /static/m1669401982.png HTTP/1.1" 200 116203
Step Entering mainpage(), duration=5235.49ms
Step Exiting mainpage(), duration=0.48ms
192.168.2.38 - - [25/Nov/2022 18:46:31] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 420
192.168.2.38 - - [25/Nov/2022 18:46:31] "GET /IMG_0797b.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 749
```

Looks like I need to dig on Safari's case now... Something must have happened with a software update...

Still, any idea someone?

Another EDIT:
I traced the above runs with tcpdump and here are the results:

For Safari:

```
    1  2022-11-26 09:06:52.095606 IP 192.168.2.38.62480 > 192.168.2.45.8080: Flags [S], seq 2184760446, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 3705418178 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
    2  2022-11-26 09:06:52.114888 IP 192.168.2.45.8080 > 192.168.2.38.62480: Flags [S.], seq 3167047311, ack 2184760447, win 65160, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2126554990 ecr 3705418178,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    3  2022-11-26 09:06:52.114980 IP 192.168.2.38.62480 > 192.168.2.45.8080: Flags [.], ack 1, win 2058, options [nop,nop,TS val 3705418197 ecr 2126554990], length 0
    4  2022-11-26 09:06:52.149725 IP 192.168.2.38.62480 > 192.168.2.45.8080: Flags [P.], seq 1:367, ack 1, win 2058, options [nop,nop,TS val 3705418232 ecr 2126554990], length 366: HTTP: GET / HTTP/1.1
    5  2022-11-26 09:06:52.150260 IP 192.168.2.38.62481 > 192.168.2.45.8080: Flags [S], seq 1267354606, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 659019529 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
    6  2022-11-26 09:06:52.153998 IP 192.168.2.45.8080 > 192.168.2.38.62480: Flags [.], ack 367, win 507, options [nop,nop,TS val 2126555043 ecr 3705418232], length 0
    7  2022-11-26 09:06:52.154002 IP 192.168.2.45.8080 > 192.168.2.38.62481: Flags [S.], seq 3998103840, ack 1267354607, win 65160, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2126555044 ecr 659019529,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    8  2022-11-26 09:06:52.154131 IP 192.168.2.38.62481 > 192.168.2.45.8080: Flags [.], ack 1, win 2058, options [nop,nop,TS val 659019533 ecr 2126555044], length 0
    9  2022-11-26 09:06:52.161430 IP 192.168.2.45.8080 > 192.168.2.38.62480: Flags [P.], seq 1:18, ack 367, win 507, options [nop,nop,TS val 2126555052 ecr 3705418232], length 17: HTTP: HTTP/1.0 200 OK
   10  2022-11-26 09:06:52.161547 IP 192.168.2.38.62480 > 192.168.2.45.8080: Flags [.], ack 18, win 2058, options [nop,nop,TS val 3705418244 ecr 2126555052], length 0
   11  2022-11-26 09:06:52.161663 IP 192.168.2.45.8080 > 192.168.2.38.62480: Flags [FP.], seq 18:576, ack 367, win 507, options [nop,nop,TS val 2126555052 ecr 3705418232], length 558: HTTP
   12  2022-11-26 09:06:52.161718 IP 192.168.2.38.62480 > 192.168.2.45.8080: Flags [.], ack 577, win 2049, options [nop,nop,TS val 3705418244 ecr 2126555052], length 0
   13  2022-11-26 09:06:52.162009 IP 192.168.2.38.62480 > 192.168.2.45.8080: Flags [F.], seq 367, ack 577, win 2049, options [nop,nop,TS val 3705418244 ecr 2126555052], length 0
   14  2022-11-26 09:06:52.163498 IP 192.168.2.38.62481 > 192.168.2.45.8080: Flags [P.], seq 1:395, ack 1, win 2058, options [nop,nop,TS val 659019543 ecr 2126555044], length 394: HTTP: GET /IMG_0797b.jpg HTTP/1.1
   15  2022-11-26 09:06:52.168534 IP 192.168.2.45.8080 > 192.168.2.38.62480: Flags [.], ack 368, win 507, options [nop,nop,TS val 2126555057 ecr 3705418244], length 0
   16  2022-11-26 09:06:52.171578 IP 192.168.2.45.8080 > 192.168.2.38.62481: Flags [.], ack 395, win 506, options [nop,nop,TS val 2126555059 ecr 659019543], length 0
   17  2022-11-26 09:06:52.171581 IP 192.168.2.45.8080 > 192.168.2.38.62481: Flags [P.], seq 1:25, ack 395, win 506, options [nop,nop,TS val 2126555062 ecr 659019543], length 24: HTTP: HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found
   18  2022-11-26 09:06:52.171654 IP 192.168.2.38.62481 > 192.168.2.45.8080: Flags [.], ack 25, win 2058, options [nop,nop,TS val 659019551 ecr 2126555062], length 0
   19  2022-11-26 09:06:52.174711 IP 192.168.2.45.8080 > 192.168.2.38.62481: Flags [FP.], seq 25:912, ack 395, win 506, options [nop,nop,TS val 2126555062 ecr 659019543], length 887: HTTP
   20  2022-11-26 09:06:52.174778 IP 192.168.2.38.62481 > 192.168.2.45.8080: Flags [.], ack 913, win 2044, options [nop,nop,TS val 659019554 ecr 2126555062], length 0
   21  2022-11-26 09:06:52.174940 IP 192.168.2.38.62481 > 192.168.2.45.8080: Flags [F.], seq 395, ack 913, win 2048, options [nop,nop,TS val 659019554 ecr 2126555062], length 0
   22  2022-11-26 09:06:52.183915 IP 192.168.2.45.8080 > 192.168.2.38.62481: Flags [.], ack 396, win 506, options [nop,nop,TS val 2126555069 ecr 659019554], length 0
   23  2022-11-26 09:06:55.910047 IP 192.168.2.38.62482 > 192.168.2.45.8080: Flags [S], seq 4155419589, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 3733982721 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
   24  2022-11-26 09:06:55.914923 IP 192.168.2.38.62483 > 192.168.2.45.8080: Flags [S], seq 2706965381, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 17610542 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
   25  2022-11-26 09:06:55.930614 IP 192.168.2.45.8080 > 192.168.2.38.62482: Flags [S.], seq 1658545548, ack 4155419590, win 65160, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2126558805 ecr 3733982721,nop,wscale 7], length 0
   26  2022-11-26 09:06:55.930618 IP 192.168.2.45.8080 > 192.168.2.38.62483: Flags [S.], seq 2519418621, ack 2706965382, win 65160, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2126558808 ecr 17610542,nop,wscale 7], length 0
   27  2022-11-26 09:06:55.930695 IP 192.168.2.38.62482 > 192.168.2.45.8080: Flags [.], ack 1, win 2058, options [nop,nop,TS val 3733982742 ecr 2126558805], length 0
   28  2022-11-26 09:06:55.930696 IP 192.168.2.38.62483 > 192.168.2.45.8080: Flags [.], ack 1, win 2058, options [nop,nop,TS val 17610558 ecr 2126558808], length 0
   29  2022-11-26 09:06:55.931305 IP 192.168.2.38.62483 > 192.168.2.45.8080: Flags [P.], seq 1:411, ack 1, win 2058, options [nop,nop,TS val 17610558 ecr 2126558808], length 410: HTTP: GET /mesures1 HTTP/1.1
   30  2022-11-26 09:06:55.956279 IP 192.168.2.45.8080 > 192.168.2.38.62483: Flags [.], ack 411, win 506, options [nop,nop,TS val 2126558828 ecr 17610558], length 0
   31  2022-11-26 09:07:52.079641 IP 192.168.2.38.62482 > 192.168.2.45.8080: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 1, win 2058, options [nop,nop,TS val 3734038907 ecr 2126558805], length 0
   32  2022-11-26 09:07:52.085430 IP 192.168.2.45.8080 > 192.168.2.38.62482: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 2, win 510, options [nop,nop,TS val 2126614988 ecr 3734038907], length 0
   33  2022-11-26 09:07:52.085703 IP 192.168.2.38.62482 > 192.168.2.45.8080: Flags [.], ack 2, win 2058, options [nop,nop,TS val 3734038913 ecr 2126614988], length 0
   34  2022-11-26 09:07:52.099562 IP 192.168.2.45.8080 > 192.168.2.38.62483: Flags [P.], seq 1:18, ack 411, win 506, options [nop,nop,TS val 2126615002 ecr 17610558], length 17: HTTP: HTTP/1.0 200 OK
   35  2022-11-26 09:07:52.099665 IP 192.168.2.38.62483 > 192.168.2.45.8080: Flags [.], ack 18, win 2058, options [nop,nop,TS val 17666743 ecr 2126615002], length 0
   36  2022-11-26 09:07:52.100616 IP 192.168.2.45.8080 > 192.168.2.38.62483: Flags [.], seq 18:1466, ack 411, win 506, options [nop,nop,TS val 2126615002 ecr 17610558], length 1448: HTTP
```

and for Chrome:

```
    1  2022-11-26 09:05:42.611450 IP 192.168.2.38.62460 > 192.168.2.45.8080: Flags [S], seq 2095142129, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 3839217551 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
    2  2022-11-26 09:05:42.612254 IP 192.168.2.38.62461 > 192.168.2.45.8080: Flags [S], seq 804032161, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 4277753475 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
    3  2022-11-26 09:05:42.630577 IP 192.168.2.45.8080 > 192.168.2.38.62460: Flags [S.], seq 2459005876, ack 2095142130, win 65160, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2126485509 ecr 3839217551,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    4  2022-11-26 09:05:42.630580 IP 192.168.2.45.8080 > 192.168.2.38.62461: Flags [S.], seq 2796395318, ack 804032162, win 65160, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2126485512 ecr 4277753475,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    5  2022-11-26 09:05:42.630677 IP 192.168.2.38.62460 > 192.168.2.45.8080: Flags [.], ack 1, win 2058, options [nop,nop,TS val 3839217571 ecr 2126485509], length 0
    6  2022-11-26 09:05:42.630677 IP 192.168.2.38.62461 > 192.168.2.45.8080: Flags [.], ack 1, win 2058, options [nop,nop,TS val 4277753495 ecr 2126485512], length 0
    7  2022-11-26 09:05:42.630892 IP 192.168.2.38.62460 > 192.168.2.45.8080: Flags [P.], seq 1:486, ack 1, win 2058, options [nop,nop,TS val 3839217571 ecr 2126485509], length 485: HTTP: GET / HTTP/1.1
    8  2022-11-26 09:05:42.639055 IP 192.168.2.45.8080 > 192.168.2.38.62460: Flags [.], ack 486, win 506, options [nop,nop,TS val 2126485529 ecr 3839217571], length 0
    9  2022-11-26 09:05:42.644599 IP 192.168.2.45.8080 > 192.168.2.38.62460: Flags [P.], seq 1:18, ack 486, win 506, options [nop,nop,TS val 2126485538 ecr 3839217571], length 17: HTTP: HTTP/1.0 200 OK
   10  2022-11-26 09:05:42.644676 IP 192.168.2.38.62460 > 192.168.2.45.8080: Flags [.], ack 18, win 2058, options [nop,nop,TS val 3839217585 ecr 2126485538], length 0
   11  2022-11-26 09:05:42.645054 IP 192.168.2.45.8080 > 192.168.2.38.62460: Flags [FP.], seq 18:576, ack 486, win 506, options [nop,nop,TS val 2126485538 ecr 3839217571], length 558: HTTP
   12  2022-11-26 09:05:42.645104 IP 192.168.2.38.62460 > 192.168.2.45.8080: Flags [.], ack 577, win 2049, options [nop,nop,TS val 3839217585 ecr 2126485538], length 0
   13  2022-11-26 09:05:42.645405 IP 192.168.2.38.62460 > 192.168.2.45.8080: Flags [F.], seq 486, ack 577, win 2049, options [nop,nop,TS val 3839217585 ecr 2126485538], length 0
   14  2022-11-26 09:05:42.650632 IP 192.168.2.45.8080 > 192.168.2.38.62460: Flags [.], ack 487, win 506, options [nop,nop,TS val 2126485544 ecr 3839217585], length 0
   15  2022-11-26 09:05:42.654458 IP 192.168.2.38.62461 > 192.168.2.45.8080: Flags [P.], seq 1:408, ack 1, win 2058, options [nop,nop,TS val 4277753518 ecr 2126485512], length 407: HTTP: GET /IMG_0797b.jpg HTTP/1.1
   16  2022-11-26 09:05:42.685107 IP 192.168.2.45.8080 > 192.168.2.38.62461: Flags [.], ack 408, win 506, options [nop,nop,TS val 2126485576 ecr 4277753518], length 0
   17  2022-11-26 09:05:42.685110 IP 192.168.2.45.8080 > 192.168.2.38.62461: Flags [P.], seq 1:25, ack 408, win 506, options [nop,nop,TS val 2126485579 ecr 4277753518], length 24: HTTP: HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found
   18  2022-11-26 09:05:42.685198 IP 192.168.2.38.62461 > 192.168.2.45.8080: Flags [.], ack 25, win 2058, options [nop,nop,TS val 4277753549 ecr 2126485579], length 0
   19  2022-11-26 09:05:42.685314 IP 192.168.2.45.8080 > 192.168.2.38.62461: Flags [FP.], seq 25:912, ack 408, win 506, options [nop,nop,TS val 2126485580 ecr 4277753518], length 887: HTTP
   20  2022-11-26 09:05:42.685401 IP 192.168.2.38.62461 > 192.168.2.45.8080: Flags [.], ack 913, win 2044, options [nop,nop,TS val 4277753549 ecr 2126485580], length 0
   21  2022-11-26 09:05:42.685705 IP 192.168.2.38.62461 > 192.168.2.45.8080: Flags [F.], seq 408, ack 913, win 2048, options [nop,nop,TS val 4277753549 ecr 2126485580], length 0
   22  2022-11-26 09:05:42.697704 IP 192.168.2.45.8080 > 192.168.2.38.62461: Flags [.], ack 409, win 506, options [nop,nop,TS val 2126485584 ecr 4277753549], length 0
   23  2022-11-26 09:05:47.451656 IP 192.168.2.38.62462 > 192.168.2.45.8080: Flags [S], seq 28132342, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 3630044781 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
   24  2022-11-26 09:05:47.452628 IP 192.168.2.38.62463 > 192.168.2.45.8080: Flags [S], seq 2568114900, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 3045267964 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
   25  2022-11-26 09:05:47.471995 IP 192.168.2.45.8080 > 192.168.2.38.62462: Flags [S.], seq 3886425570, ack 28132343, win 65160, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2126490350 ecr 3630044781,nop,wscale 7], length 0
   26  2022-11-26 09:05:47.472000 IP 192.168.2.45.8080 > 192.168.2.38.62463: Flags [S.], seq 3651933573, ack 2568114901, win 65160, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2126490351 ecr 3045267964,nop,wscale 7], length 0
   27  2022-11-26 09:05:47.472119 IP 192.168.2.38.62462 > 192.168.2.45.8080: Flags [.], ack 1, win 2058, options [nop,nop,TS val 3630044802 ecr 2126490350], length 0
   28  2022-11-26 09:05:47.472120 IP 192.168.2.38.62463 > 192.168.2.45.8080: Flags [.], ack 1, win 2058, options [nop,nop,TS val 3045267985 ecr 2126490351], length 0
   29  2022-11-26 09:05:47.472297 IP 192.168.2.38.62462 > 192.168.2.45.8080: Flags [P.], seq 1:504, ack 1, win 2058, options [nop,nop,TS val 3630044802 ecr 2126490350], length 503: HTTP: GET /mesures1 HTTP/1.1
   30  2022-11-26 09:05:47.479264 IP 192.168.2.45.8080 > 192.168.2.38.62462: Flags [.], ack 504, win 506, options [nop,nop,TS val 2126490372 ecr 3630044802], length 0
   31  2022-11-26 09:05:47.494318 IP 192.168.2.45.8080 > 192.168.2.38.62462: Flags [P.], seq 1:18, ack 504, win 506, options [nop,nop,TS val 2126490387 ecr 3630044802], length 17: HTTP: HTTP/1.0 200 OK
   32  2022-11-26 09:05:47.494323 IP 192.168.2.45.8080 > 192.168.2.38.62462: Flags [.], seq 18:1466, ack 504, win 506, options [nop,nop,TS val 2126490388 ecr 3630044802], length 1448: HTTP
   33  2022-11-26 09:05:47.494324 IP 192.168.2.45.8080 > 192.168.2.38.62462: Flags [.], seq 1466:2914, ack 504, win 506, options [nop,nop,TS val 2126490388 ecr 3630044802], length 1448: HTTP
   34  2022-11-26 09:05:47.494383 IP 192.168.2.45.8080 > 192.168.2.38.62462: Flags [P.], seq 2914:4362, ack 504, win 506, options [nop,nop,TS val 2126490388 ecr 3630044802], length 1448: HTTP
   35  2022-11-26 09:05:47.494385 IP 192.168.2.45.8080 > 192.168.2.38.62462: Flags [FP.], seq 4362:4529, ack 504, win 506, options [nop,nop,TS val 2126490388 ecr 3630044802], length 167: HTTP
   36  2022-11-26 09:05:47.494461 IP 192.168.2.38.62462 > 192.168.2.45.8080: Flags [.], ack 18, win 2058, options [nop,nop,TS val 3630044824 ecr 2126490387], length 0
   37  2022-11-26 09:05:47.494461 IP 192.168.2.38.62462 > 192.168.2.45.8080: Flags [.], ack 1466, win 2035, options [nop,nop,TS val 3630044824 ecr 2126490388], length 0
   38  2022-11-26 09:05:47.494462 IP 192.168.2.38.62462 > 192.168.2.45.8080: Flags [.], ack 2914, win 2013, options [nop,nop,TS val 3630044824 ecr 2126490388], length 0
   39  2022-11-26 09:05:47.494517 IP 192.168.2.38.62462 > 192.168.2.45.8080: Flags [.], ack 4362, win 1990, options [nop,nop,TS val 3630044824 ecr 2126490388], length 0
   40  2022-11-26 09:05:47.494517 IP 192.168.2.38.62462 > 192.168.2.45.8080: Flags [.], ack 4530, win 1988, options [nop,nop,TS val 3630044824 ecr 2126490388], length 0
   41  2022-11-26 09:05:47.494937 IP 192.168.2.38.62462 > 192.168.2.45.8080: Flags [.], ack 4530, win 2048, options [nop,nop,TS val 3630044824 ecr 2126490388], length 0
   42  2022-11-26 09:05:47.497062 IP 192.168.2.38.62462 > 192.168.2.45.8080: Flags [F.], seq 504, ack 4530, win 2048, options [nop,nop,TS val 3630044827 ecr 2126490388], length 0
   43  2022-11-26 09:05:47.509210 IP 192.168.2.45.8080 > 192.168.2.38.62462: Flags [.], ack 505, win 506, options [nop,nop,TS val 2126490396 ecr 3630044827], length 0
   44  2022-11-26 09:05:52.352627 IP 192.168.2.38.62463 > 192.168.2.45.8080: Flags [P.], seq 1:504, ack 1, win 2058, options [nop,nop,TS val 3045272865 ecr 2126490351], length 503: HTTP: GET / HTTP/1.1
```

I see some additional exchanges with Safari and a delay at line number 30-31. Could no put more due to space constraint...

Comment: `Step Entering mesures1, duration=40161.20ms` If I understand your timing code correctly, this is just saying that 40 seconds elapsed between the last page request and now. It's measuring how long you take to click on a new page, not how long processing the data takes.

Comment: Could be if I were to wait but I clicked as soon as the page appeared to reduce "Key-Think" time as much as possible. For example, the delay of the first Step Entering mainpage(), duration=50455.94ms is between the call to the server and the answer. Step Entering mesures1, duration=59996.11ms is from clicking the option from main menu to the time the mesure1 page appeared and the Step Entering mesures1, duration=40161.20ms is the time from asking the chart in the same mesures1 page.